# Discrepancy of 'Temporary Files' sizes

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

While managing my temporary files I noticed that there is a discrepancy when I am told how much space my temporary files are taking up. For instance when I use 'cleanmgr' Windows 10 shows me the following (on Drive C):

[image]

It shows the total amount of space to be gained as 379MB (this is with ALL fields selected).

Now in contrast, if I use System Settings from the start menu I get this:
[image]

To observe the difference I clicked on that entry, and it simply says:

***"Some temporary  files are needed by apps. Below is a list of  files you can remove now. Scanning:"***

and the progress bar never changes (I have left it now for over 20 minutes with nothing in the list being populated).

So my question is this; do these two different Windows temporary file management programs look at the same data, or are they compiling the amounts from different sources? I ask this because the discrepancy is fairly significant from 379MB to 31GB.

Comment: If you want to know what’s using space, I suggest using an analyzer like TreeSize Free. Run it as Admin so it can see everything.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, thanks I know of this app, however this does not address the issue I was asking about. Thank you!

Comment: If discrepancy is that dramatic then obviously they're looking different things. BTW if you click Temporary files you'll see items that make up the space. Scans by this app however take forever but will at some point finish.

Comment: Click on the Down Arrow beside Temporary Files (right side) and see what is there. That will not be the same as the Disk Cleanup number. Apples and Oranges.